# apparent bug when repopulating a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a created a simple example to illustrate what I have found. I also have a "fix", but I don't think I should need it!

I am using VS2010 and .NET 4. My form has a DataGridView (dgvTest), and a checkbox (CheckBox1). I am selecting 2 or 3 fields from a table, depending on whether the checkbox is checked (which it is initially).

My possible SQL statements are `"SELECT ID,strForenames,strSurname FROM tblAlumni"` and `"SELECT strForenames,strSurname FROM tblAlumni"`.

I have used SQL Profiler to confirm that these are the queries sent to the DB.

All seems well when I load the form (I see 3 fields, in the order I expect), and when I uncheck the box (I see 2 fields, in the order I expect).

However, when I check it again, the ID field appears THIRD in the columns of the DataGridView, not first!

I have found a couple of reports of something similar to this (mis)behaviour on the Net, but folks just seem to find some other way to do the job rather than ask is this a problem with DataGridView that needs fixed.

Since I have been able to recreate it with a simple example I have some confidence (only some!) that I am not missing anything obvious.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    loadGRID()
End Sub

Private Sub loadGRID()
    Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True")
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT " & IIf(CheckBox1.Checked, "ID,", "") & "strForenames,strSurname FROM tblAlumni", sqlConn)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds)
    dgvTest.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    sqlConn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    loadGRID()
End Sub
End Class
```

So my question is, do your experts agree this is a bug? The "fix" is to wipe the DataGridView between repopulations, but I'm not sure I should have to?

```
    dgvTest.DataSource = Nothing
    dgvTest.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a BindingSource as a glue between the 'datasource' and the datagridview works very nicely for me, sorry I know that doesn't answer whether this is a bug as I am not sure.

(c#)

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();

bindingSource.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
bindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *However, when I check it again, the ID field appears THIRD in the columns of the DataGridView, not first!*

Thats the expected behaviour as the columns strForenames and strSurname already exist.

Try **dgvTest.Columns.Clear()** before and **dgvTest.refresh** after changing the datasource